# Need help on Mod Rewrite .htaccess parent folder and 1 subfolder

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am not really good on understand .htaccess rewrite, and this one give me headache.

I have `domain.com` , and 1 folder called: `app/webroot/`

1. I want everything: `domain.com/*` will be rewrite to folder `domain.com/app/webroot/*`
2. Then this is make me crazy. I have 1 folder for admin, called `"system"` under domain.com too. Everything under domain.com/system will not be rewrite to the webroot.
3. And finally, I want `system/something` will be rewrite to `/system/index.php?subpage=something`

Really sorry if you guy think this is easy and I can not do it, but I stuck with it whole days already.

Here is what I have tried to do:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/?(system)/?([^/]+)/?$ /system/index.php?subpage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(system)/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /system/index.php?subpage=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(system)/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /system/index.php?subpage=$1&action=$2&param=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm, i got it.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/?(system)/?([^/]+)/?$ /system/index.php?subpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(system)/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /system/index.php?subpage=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(system)/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /system/index.php?subpage=$2&action=$3&param=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
```